# Which is the better way to implement heartbeat on the client side for websockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, client-server

On the Server side for websockets there is already an ping/pong implementation where the server sends a ping and client replies with a pong to let the server node whether a client is connected or not. But there isn't something implemented in reverse to let the client know if the server is still connected to them.

There are two ways to go about this I have read:

- 1. Every client sends a message to server every x seconds and whenever
     an error is thrown when sending, that means the server is down, so
     reconnect.
- 2. Server sends a message to every client every x seconds, the client receives this message and updates a variable on the client, and on the client side you have a thread that constantly checks every x seconds which checks if this variable has changed, if it hasn't in a while it means it hasn't received a message from the server and you can assume the server is down so reestablish a connection.

You can achieve trying to figure out on client side whether the server is still online using either methods. The first one you'll be sending traffic to the server whereas the second one you'll be sending traffic out of the server. Both seem easy enough to implement but I'm not so sure which is the better way in terms of being the more efficient/cost effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server upload speeds are higher than client upload speeds, but server CPUs are an expensive resource while client CPUs are relatively cheap. Unloading logic onto the client is a more cost-effective approach...

Having said that, servers **must** implement this specific logic (actually, all `ping`/`timeout` logic), otherwise they might be left with ["half-open" sockets](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) that drain resources but aren't connected to any client.

Remember that sockets (file descriptors) are a limited resource. Not only do they use memory even when no traffic is present, but they prevent new clients from connecting when the resource is maxed out.

Hence, servers must clear out dead sockets, either using timeouts or by implementing `ping`.

#### P.S.

I'm not a `node.js` expert, but this type of logic should be implemented using the Websocket protocol `ping` rather than by your application. You should probably look into the `node.js` server / websocket framework and check how to enable `ping`-ing.

You should set `pings` to accommodate your specific environment. i.e., if you host on Heroku, than Heroku will implement a timeout of ~55 seconds and your `ping`s should be sent before this timeout occurs.

Comment: Browsers do not expose the WebSocket `ping` mechanism, so for these an application-level mechanism is required so that the client can detect a disconnect. Otherwise the WebSocket library should expose the `ping` mechanism, and that should, of course, be used.